# How to write the callback for popup menu in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a table with different types of soils and values of porosities for each soil.    Now, I have to create a GUI with popup menu from which i can select a type of soil, then the corresponding porosity will be displayed in a static text.

```
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata,handles)

str = get(hObject, 'String');

val = get(hObject,'Value');

switch str{val};

case 'Clay'

c = 45;

case 'Sand'

c= 30

end

set(handles.text1,c);
```

I would like to know the problem with coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the last line to

```
set(handles.text1,'string',num2str(c));
```